# What algebraic manipulations make this two equations equivalent?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, density

I have a very basic mathematical backround. I kind of understand the concept of a partial derivative but i dont know what algebraic manipulations make this two equations equivalent (the ones on 2A.4) given that density=constant/V.

[image]

Comment: Which book  ??? (on fluid mechanics ???)

Comment: @Frobenius This is a truly amazing book "THE TRAGICOMICAL HISTORY OF THERMODYNAMICS" by Truesdell. I strongly recommend it both for its content and very entertaining style, but is surely not an "introduction" to the subject.

Comment: @hyportnex  :  Many Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you need to apply the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to express the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}$ by $\frac{\partial}{\partial V}$. Using the relation between $\rho$ and $V$, we first calculate

$$\rho=M/V \Leftrightarrow V=M/\rho \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial V}{\partial \rho}=-\frac{M}{\rho^2}=-\frac{V^2}{M}\,. $$

Using these results, we can now apply the chain-rule to your problem:

$$\rho \frac{\partial p(\rho,\theta)}{\partial \rho}=(M/V)\frac{\partial V}{\partial \rho}\frac{\partial p(V,\theta)}{\partial V}=(M/V)\left(-\frac{V^2}{M}\right)\frac{\partial p(V,\theta)}{\partial V}=-V \frac{\partial p(V,\theta)}{\partial V}\,.$$

This is exactly the right-hand side of your equation.